# check if the sum is same as the product using sum of the roots of a cubic equation

Tags: python

I am learning Python and got an assignment to solve the below program. Referred some other sites and tried as per below code but don't know how to check if the sum is same as the product as the value given in assignment. Please help on this what additional code I need to add in the code.

Assignment:
program to check if the sum is same as the product. The sum of the roots of a cubic equation  ax3+ bx2 + c x +d=0 where sum=-1*b/a   product= -1*d/a.

code for the cubic equation program but how to check the sum of the roots as per the sum and product given as assignement:

```
def findcubicEquation(a, b, c): 
  
   # Find the value of coefficient 
   X = (a + b + c); 
   Y = (a * b) + (b * c) + (c * a); 
   Z = (a * b * c); 
  
   print("x^3 - " , X , 
        "x^2 + " ,Y , 
        "x - " , Z , " = 0");   
  
if __name__ == '__main__': 
  
   a = 6; 
   b = 3; 
   c = 4; 
  
   # Function Call 
   findEquation(a, b, c);
```

Comment: nit: you're calling a different function from the one defined. I also don't see an input for "d" in the argument list.

Comment: Any help on the code what changes i need to do please

Comment: I don't understand, there is a and b but no d in your function?

Comment: (ax3 + bx2 + cx + d = 0) be A, B and C. Then the given cubic equation can be represents as:ax3 + bx2 + cx + d = x3 – (A + B + C)x2 + (AB + BC +CA)x + A*B*C = 0.
Let X = (A + B + C)
Y = (AB + BC +CA)
Z = A*B*C

Comment: So you just need to return if `X == Z`?

Comment: i need to check  if the sum is same as the product where sum=-1b/a product= -1d/a.

Comment: In this case, a is 1 (coeff of x^3), so you just need to return if X == Z?

Comment: yes as to check same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think you're making some confusion i.e. you're not passing value of **`d`** and secondly you have to compare the values(answer) of **`SUM`** and **`PRODUCT`** and fuction names are different as mentioned in comment.
Why use **`d`** because you're using cubic equation and cubic equation is

Example of cubic equation

> ax3+bx2+cx+d=0

**Code**

```
def findEquation(a, b, c, d): 
  # For example X,Y and Z are roots of equation
  # X + Y + Z = -b/a
  # XYZ = -d/a  
  sum_value = -(b/a)  //Sum
  product_value = -(d/a)   //Product

  if sum_value == product_value:
    print("Product and sum are same")  
  else:
    print("not same") 
  
if __name__ == '__main__': 
  
  # As we know ax3+bx2+cx+d=0
  a = 6 
  b = 3 
  c = 4 
  d = 2

  # Function Call 
  findEquation(a, b, c, d)
```

- Coefficients are a,b,c and d
- Roots are X,Y and Z can be alpha,beta and gemma or can be p,q,r as
  you wish....
- There is no need to find the values of roots.

Comment: is it useful or not?

Comment: Hi @Adam How to write sum of series  X+X 3 + X 5 + ….  + X N  in python please help on this

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/EdibleWellmadeCallback visit this

Comment: Thanks a lot it will really be helpful for learn

Comment: But if you're at beginner level and trying to learn python believe me try it your self. What will happen at last you will throw out of the class but if you do it yourself  in near future no one will better than you. Keep my words

Comment: yes correct sure i will take your words and I am learning full fledge by solving small programs